# ALSA config: I want to set hw:0,0 as default for output and hw:1,0 as default for input

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

Here is what I currently have:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: soundplayback [sound-playback], device 0: 2030000.ssi-snd-soc-dummy-dai snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: soundcapture [sound-capture], device 0: 202c000.ssi-snd-soc-dummy-dai snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I know that if I want to use hw:1,0 as my default I can do something in my ~/.asoundrc like this

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

However I'm not sure how to set hw:0,0 as default playback and hw:1,0 as default capture.

Comment: have you looked at hda-jack-retask? it lets you click a few buttons to tune audio pins.

Comment: im using a single board computer without X. is there something I can do from the command line?

Comment: hda-jack-retask can be configured by cli or config file also, doesn't need the gui (just easier), i've not yet dabbled too much with it, it's quite a powerful tool.

Comment: This does not look like an HDA device. Anyway, use `asym`.

Comment: @CL what is asym? edit: alsa plugin found it